# Insertar onclick en los enlaces de las listas de artículos mediante plugin WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, onclick

Estaba desarrollando una cosilla de analítica web y lo quiero pasar a plugin para compartir, pero estoy algo atascado.

No sé si alguien me puede ayudar.

Lo que necesito es insertar el atributo onclick en los enlaces de las listas de artículos que suelen mostrar en el bucle de los posts:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Cuando se ejecuta el bucle, la parte del código donde necesito insertar el evento onclick es aquí:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" >
```

He intentado modificar desde el plugin que estoy creando, directamente la parte de `the_permalink` jugando un poco con las comillas dobles pero no tira (aunque sé que no es la forma correcta, os dejo el ejemplo:

```
add_filter("the_permalink", "qso_Add_Onclic");
function qso_Add_Onclic($old_Permalink)
{

 return $old_Permalink."&quot; onclick=&quot;productObject(".the_title().",".
        the_ID().",".
        get_the_author_meta('ID').",".
        get_the_category()[0]->cat_name.",". 
        //$qso_etiquetas."','".
                        wp_title() .",".
                        $old_Permalink.")";
}
```

Como resultado me da esta url pero se muestra todo comentado a pesar de las comillas dobles:

```
href="Primera imagen del PVP de Pokemon Go3184Street Of Games - Artículos de videojuegos, comics y animehttps://www.streetofgames.com/noticias/primera-imagen-del-pvp-de-pokemon-go/" onclick="productObject(,,2,Noticias,,https://www.streetofgames.com/noticias/primera-imagen-del-pvp-de-pokemon-go/)"
```

He intentado poner las comillas dobles escapadas y con ASCII sin éxito.

Esto a nivel de código directamente sobre el template, ya he conseguido hacer que funcione pero estoy trabajando para migrarlo a un plugin y estoy bloqueado en colocar el onclick.

Para los usuarios logueados, podéis ver en el enlaces el resultado final.

Gracias!

Aquí he dejado más avances sobre el tema: https://es.wordpress.org/support/topic/insertar-onclick-en-los-enlaces-de-las-listas-de-articulos-mediante-plugin/#post-96760

Answer (score 0):

Lo último que intenté hacer es acceder al dom mediante php pero no lo logré hacer funcionar:

```
add_filter("get_template_part", "qso_Add_Onclic");

// Formateando contenido para SSL
function qso_Add_Onclic($content = '') {

  $document = new DOMDocument();
  $document->loadHTML($content);

  $tags = $document->getElementsByTagName('a');
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $tag->setAttribute('onclick', "productObject("
            .the_title().",".
            the_ID().",".
            get_the_author_meta('ID').",".
            //get_the_category()[0]->cat_name.",". 
            //$qso_etiquetas."','".
            wp_title() .",".
            the_permalink().")"

    );
  }
  return $document->saveHTML();
}
```